# Layout for importing .csv intent file for IBM watson chatbot

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation, watson

I am in the process of creating a chatbot and need to import a .csv file to act as the intents. My question is regarding the layout; I currently have a list of cities however when importing should my intent name be in row A next to the city name or in row B seperated with a "," before the city ?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intents should be questions where there is a clear intent of what is being asked.

Saying "Dubai" doesn't mean anything except as a word meaning. Using city names for training in intents will not give you great results.

File format for Intents is [listed here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#importing-intents-and-examples). It is `question,intent` format.

Example:

```
Tell me the current weather conditions.,weather_conditions
Is it raining?,weather_conditions
What's the temperature?,weather_conditions
Where is your nearest location?,find_location
Do you have a store in Raleigh?,find_location
```

Entites are non standard format of `entitiy,value, synomns,...`

Example:

```
weekday,Monday,Mon
weekday,Tuesday,Tue,Tues
weekday,Wednesday,Wed
weekday,Thursday,Thur,Thu,Thurs
weekday,Friday,Fri
weekday,Saturday,Sat
weekday,Sunday,Sun
```

More [details for entities here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#importing-entities).